# Separate aggregated data in different rows

Tags: pandas, aggregate, python-2.x

I have a panda's `dataframe` with the following structure:

```
    Date        product  count
0   2016-09-01  sugar    3   
1   2016-09-01  pasta    4   
2   2016-09-01  coffee   5   
3   2016-09-02  sugar    25  
4   2016-09-02  pasta    30   
5   2016-09-02  salad    5
```

I would like to obtain the **unaggregated** data (like the picture below), but I don't know how to achieve it using pandas. In `apache spark` it would be easier, I could use [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sql.functions#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) after some trivial transformations.

```
    Date        product  
0   2016-09-01  sugar
1   2016-09-01  sugar
2   2016-09-01  sugar
3   2016-09-01  pasta
.   .           .
.   .           .
.   .           .
?   2016-09-02  salad
```

Comment: basically you can do `df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values,df['count'])]`

Comment: @EdChum what happens if I have more than one column? For example, I have a count for purchases, another for returns and I want to obtain those in different rows?

Comment: You'd have to do it separately for each count and then merge/concat them after

Comment: @EdChum, i would suggest one cosmetic correction: `df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df.pop('count'))]`

Comment: @MaxU yes I guess that's actually what the OP is after